# NSFetchRequest sometimes doesn't return anything but I can find it

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm have a `NSFetchRequest` I create as part of a `NSFetchedResultsController`.  The predicate is designed to find a specific object that has a relationship to 3 other objects:

```
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@ && %K = %@ && %K = %@ && (delete == null || delete == 0)",
                 CDPerformanceDataRelationships.group, group,
                 CDPerformanceDataRelationships.game, game,
                 CDPerformanceDataRelationships.user, user]
```

This all looks right except the fetch request doesn't always return an object (there should only be one object returned in this case). Most of the time it does, but sometimes it returns an empty array.

I manually keep track of the relationships in all my Core Data objects in order to facilitate syncing to a server.  So I can change the predicate to search off the respective IDs the fetch request works:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@ && %K = %@ && %K = %@ && (delete == null || delete == 0)",
             CDPerformanceDataAttributes.groupID, group.groupID,
             CDPerformanceDataAttributes.gameID, game.gameID,
             CDPerformanceDataAttributes.userID, user.userID]
```

The frustrating part is that the above fetch actually returns an object with the exact relationships I was looking for in the previous fetch.

Does any one know why this might be?

#### Update

I use Mogenerator to create my Core Data `NSManagedObject` subclasses.  Mogenerator creates an enum (NSString) with the Attributes and Relationships for the class.  So `CDPerformanceDataRelationships.<property>` resolves to a string that is the key path for the specific relationship in question.  `CDPerformanceDataAttributes.<property>` resolves to a string for specific attributes.

All of this is done on the main thread.  While I do have other contexts on a background thread, these are self-contained within their class and are not accessible outside the class.

Also, I pass in the Entity name, Predicate and Sort descriptors into a generalized private class method that constructs the Fetch request and NSFetchedResultsController.  There are about a dozen other methods that use this to construct Fetch Requests and a NSFetchedResultsController without any problem.

#### More Info

**Deleted Objects**
I have a boolean attribute called "delete" on all my Core Data objects. I flag objects as needing to be deleted and filter them out during fetches. When the app first starts up, I fetch those objects and delete them before the rest of the app has a chance to use them. That is the only time I ever actually delete an object from Core Data.  This is why you see `(delete == null || delete == 0)`.

**Object Types**
All properties that end in ID are a `NSNumber`.  All other properties you see (group, game, user) are Core Data objects, subclassed from `NSManagedObject`.  The Core Data objects do have their own `<object>id` (ex: gameID) property that matches the related property on the retrieved object. The fetch request that's failing is looking for an object with specific relationships to other core data objects.  The fetch request that's succeeding is looking for attributes on the core data object (the IDs).

**There are no duplicates**
I checked the memory addresses of the related core data objects in the object that was returned.  They match, pointer equality.  Meaning that `object.group == group`, `object.game == game`, etc.

Comment: Core Data is very buggy, and in my opinion, you should just work around these little things, because a work around is usually easier and more robust than a fix, at least with Core Data, and in my experience.

Comment: What are `group`, `game`, and `user`, exactly? Instances of what class?

Comment: They're instances of other `NSManagedObject` classes in Core Data.  The groupID, gameID and userID are NSNumber (attributes) on the PerformanceData object.

Comment: Core Data isn't known to be buggy at all; I'd downvote duci9y's comment were it possible. `%K` is intended to correlate to a string. What is `CDPerformanceDataAttributes` and are `groupID`, `gameID` and `userID` all string properties that name Core Data managed properties? Similarly, are you using `group`, `game` and `user` on the correct queue/thread? Are you sure the predicate you form isn't being used on a different queue/thread? If the framework you're using to issue the fetch request isn't explicit, have you tried using the `objectID`s instead?

Comment: I have experienced something similar. It is not a bug. Agree Core Data is not buggy, programmers are buggy. In my experience it is to do with when and how I instantiated the `NSFetchedResultsController`. The hint that reminded me is that you receive the object you're looking for from your previous fetch. My suggestion - review how and when you instantiate your FRC.

Comment: @Tommy See my update, but yes all of the `.<property>` are strings that name the Core Data object attributes/relationships.  Everything is done on the main thread.

Comment: What's the story on `(delete == null || delete == 0)` in the predicate? What is that intended to do?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have a boolean attribute called "delete" on all my Core Data objects.  I flag objects as needing to be deleted and filter them out during fetches.  When the app first starts up, I fetch those objects and delete them before the rest of the app has a chance to use them.  That is the only time I ever actually delete an object from Core Data.